# Interactively piping through grep

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I have a script which takes fairly long to execute. Throughout the process, it is continuously outputing to stdout. I would like to have some of these mesages interactively displayed in some sort of *progress dialog* using a graphical utility like kdialog or zenity for instance, but that's not relevant here, for the solution I seek should not depend on it.

To accomplish this I'm trying the following

```
<call to actual job> | egrep <regex> | xargs -I{} <call to display utility> {}
```

The problem is that once I insert the call to `egrep` the output is sort of accumulated untill the main job finishes, before it is effectively piped on to `xargs`. If I take `egrep` out, then it works as expected and the status mesages are interactively piped on to `xargs`, but then a lot of irelevant information is displayed.

I've been searching all over the internet and reading the manual for `grep` to no avail, does anyone know how I could achieve the desired behavior?

**Practical Example**

I believe the following example behaves analogously to my real case.

```
(sleep 1; echo A; sleep 1; echo 0; sleep 1; echo B) | egrep -i [a-z] | xargs -I{} echo {}
```

Comment: What is the regex you are using for `egrep`? Perhaps there's another tool to accomplish the same thing that doesn't buffer its output so aggressively.

Comment: @mbratch at the moment I'm just matching a couple of words and displaying the lines where they appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the exact answer this question: `grep` and its variations have an option to force flushing line by line.

**man** is not very helpful

> **--line-buffered**
>          Use line buffering on output.  This can cause a performance penalty.

that's why I overlooked this option at first.

Fortunately `grep --help` makes it more obvious.

> **--line-buffered** flush output on every line

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a less buffered command. I'm not sure about awk but you could do this with it:

```
<call to actual job> | awk '/regex/' | xargs -I{} <call to display utility> {}
```

Another with sed:

```
<call to actual job> | sed -n '/regex/p' | xargs -I{} <call to display utility> {}
```

And my favorite for that actually would be bash:

```
function filter {
    while read -r __; do
        [[ $__ =~ $1 ]] && echo "$__"
    done
}

<call to actual job> | filter "<regex>" | xargs -I{} <call to display utility> {}
```

It's could be a little slower but it certainly doesn't buffer output much.

Comment: Unfortunately neither `awk` nor `sed` worked, they behaved exacly like `grep` for my practical example, however the third option worked like a charm. I'll test it for my real use case and if it works I'll accept the answer.